# Template for event archive

Tags: templating

I've hacked this together to create an event archive listing, and although it works, I'm wondering if it's 'correct' or could be done more succinctly?

```
{% set pastEvents = craft.entries.section('eventsEntry').orderBy('eventDate') %}
   {% for date, entries in pastEvents | group("pastEvents.eventDate|date('Y')") %}
        <h4>{{ date }}</h4>
            <ul>
                {% for event in pastEvents.all() if event.eventDate <= now %}
                <li>
                    {{ event.eventDate|date('d/m/y') }}
                    {{ event.title }}
                </li>                   
                {% endfor %} 
            </ul>   
   {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Looks good to me. For the most part if it works for you it's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of grabbing *all* entries in the `eventsEntry` section, then filtering by the current date/time, you could do the filtering on the database side first, so you're returning only the entries you're interested in.

Something like this:

```
{% set pastEvents = craft.entries.section('eventsEntry').eventdate('<= ' ~ now|atom) %}

{% for date, entries in pastEvents | group("pastEvents.eventdate|date('Y')") %}
    <h4>{{ date }}</h4>

    <ul>
        {% for event in pastEvents.all() %}
            <li>
                {{ event.eventdate|date('d/m/y') }}
                {{ event.title }}
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```